# Why is index() not printing the index of the currently read character from the input text as intended?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing a Python code, where I'm truncating the starting part of a large block of text. For that, I wrote the following:

```
# chatText is the variable where the text block is stored. lbCount is for counting the number of line breaks.
lbCount = 0
i = 0
for character in chatText:
    print(character)
    if (character == '\n'):
        lbCount = lbCount + 1
        print("Number of line breaks seen:", lbCount)
        print("Current position in text:", chatText.index(character))
        # Store the text after the 4th line break.
        if (lbCount == 4):
            i = chatText.index(character)+1
            print("The index from where the chats begin is:", i)
            chats = eval(f"chatText[i:]")
            break
```

I don't know why, but the `chatText.index(character)` is always returning 13. This is interesting because that was the intended value from an earlier version of this code. However, if I modify the code as such:

```
lbCount = 0
i = 0
for character in chatText:
    print(character)
    i = i + 1 # Putting a simple counter variable here, which counts each character encountered.
    if (character == '\n'):
        lbCount = lbCount + 1
        print("Number of line breaks seen:", lbCount)
        print("Current position in text:", chatText.index(character))
        if (lbCount == 4):
            print("The index from where the chats begin is:", i)
            chats = eval(f"chatText[i:]")
            break
```

It gives the intended value (117 in my case), and the required block of text is stored in `chats` variable. The `chatText.index(character)` still gives the value 13 in this case too. I was wondering about why is this happening. I haven't restarted my computer yet, so I don't know if it's a cache issue or something (using the term loosely here).

Comment: Have you tried reading the documentation for `.index`? This behavior will be clear

Comment: `index(char)` returns the index of the *first occurrence* of char in your string. It doesn't intuit that you mean a particular occurrence that you've got to in your loop. If you want the index you've got to in your loop, use `enumerate`.

Comment: @khelwood Argh! I was under the impression that it'd give me the *current* index of the character being read, and not the first occurence. Thanks for the quick reply :D.